# Why can I not pass an additional parameter when using array_map within PHP?

Tags: php

I've come up with this SO question which nearly describes my question:

[Array_map function in php with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745447/array-map-function-in-php-with-parameter)

For me, I need to pass a second parameter to a custom sanitize array data function which tells the function to only sanitize as a text field - even it's numeric:

```
function cstm_sanitize_array_data( $value, bool $override_is_string = false ) 
    if ( empty( $value ) ) {
        return $value;
    }

    $value = wp_unslash( $value );

    if ( ! $override_is_string && is_numeric( $value ) ) {
        $value = absint( $value );
    }

    if ( $override_is_string || is_string( $value ) ) {
        error_log( 'Override: ' . $override_is_string );
        $value = sanitize_text_field( $value );
    }

    return $value;
}
```

When I call my function this way:

```
$sorted_product_ids = array_map( 'cstm_sanitize_array_data', $_POST['sorted_product_ids'] ?? null, [ true ] );
```

I can see that the first error logging is true and all the next ones are false. This results in the fact that my values like `015` are stripped and results in `15` only because the `absint()` function completely makes sure, that it's a valid number. So somehow my `$override_is_string` param is only set once and is totally ignored after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$override_is_string` is iterate at once  internally because the supplementary array has only 1 count so that `$override_is_string`will be false in the next `iteration` of the map, you can fix it by making array that same count with the `sorted_product_ids`

You may use `array_fill` to generate the array with value of `true`

```
$sorted_product_ids = array_map(
  'cstm_sanitize_array_data', 
   $_POST['sorted_product_ids'] ?? [], 
   array_fill(0,count($_POST['sorted_product_ids'] ?? [],true)
);
```

You may see this [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/IevIi) or this [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/rpY7u)

Comment: Are you sure the statement is correct? Seems to be faulty to me :/

Comment: yes, it's considered correct you can see in the array_map docs in php manual

Comment: My IDE means that the code is not complete - maybe my issue. I'll see.