# Specifying object in PHP Array from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to use a specific object type from a JSON feed, and am having a hard time specifying it. Using the code below I grab and print the specific array (max) I want,

```
$jsonurl = "LINK";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json,true);
$max_output = $json_output["max"];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($max_output);
echo '</pre>';
```

And from the Array below, all I want to work with is the [1] objects in each array. How can I specify and get just those values?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1309924800000
        [1] => 28877
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1310011200000
        [1] => 29807
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1310097600000
        [1] => 33345
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1310184000000
        [1] => 33345
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1310270400000
        [1] => 33345
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1310356800000
        [1] => 40703
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could fetch those values with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$max_output = array_map(function($val) { return $val[1]; }, $json_output["max"]);
```

This requires PHP 5.3, if you use an earlier version, then you can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to achieve similar results:

```
$max_output = array_map(create_function('$val', 'return $val[1];'), $json_output["max"]);
```

Comment: +1 for `array_map`, which, **IMHO**, is a more semantically appropriate solution than looping. It's worth noting that when I've benchmarked `array_map` vs. `foreach` performance on controlled tasks the loop is usually a fair amount faster than the `array_map` call. This is anecdotal evidence, though, so take it with a grain of salt and run your own benchmarks for oft-executed code blocks.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Now $max_output shows only the objects I wanted. Huge thanks!

Comment: @user1209756 Then you should accept the answer! (click the checkbox and make it green)

Comment: @rdlowrey: thank you very much for the comment. A quick google-session turns out that there are other benchmarks which support your point. I guess if the input size is large enough it's definitely better to use `foreach`. But for small arrays it's just a matter of taste (meaning, the difference won't be significant).

Answer (score 1):

When you need to create new array which will contain only second values, you may use either `foreach` loop which will create it or use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (just for fun with [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) available since php 5.3.0):

```
$newArray = array_map( function( $item){
    return $item[1]
},$array);
```

Then you want to use last ("max" -> considering array with numeric keys) item, you can use [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

```
return end( $item);
```

And when you can process your data sequentially (eg. it's not part of some big `getData()` function) you can rather use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach( $items as $key => $val){
    echo $val[1] . " is my number\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get `$max_output`...

```
for( $i = 0; $i < length( $max_output ); $i++ ) {
    $max_output[$i] = $max_output[$i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$ones = array();
foreach ($max_output as $r)
    $ones[] = $r[1];
```