# how to get a column from a find result?

Tags: php

It is a many to many relations between items and images tables.Now I want to get the 'file_name' of images and to display the image on the page.How to do it?

```
$items = Model_Item::find($id, array('related' => array('images')));
$result = $items->to_array();
```

the output of above statement is such an array:

```
array(18) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "27"
  ["product_code"]=>
  string(3) "666"
  ["item_color_id"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["item_size_type_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["classification_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "66666"
  ["display_name"]=>
  string(8) "goods_18"
  ["usual_price"]=>
  string(5) "88888"
  ["selling_price"]=>
  string(3) "888"
  ["point_ratio"]=>
  string(2) "88"
  ["description"]=>
  string(3) "888"
  ["publish_start_datetime"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["publish_end_datetime"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["publish_flag"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["deleted_at"]=>
  NULL
  ["images"]=>
  array(1) {
    [6]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["file_name"]=>
      string(36) "ea4c6011154b543e710b8809ed39b9db.jpg"
      ["content_type"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["deleted_at"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `echo $result['images']['file_name']`, not `echo $result['images']['image_name']` upstairs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)   which Return the values from a single column in the input array

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo $result['images']['image_name'];
```