# Peeling an array! best approach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a more professional method to solve a very simple problem.

I have an array like :

```
$originalArray = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 22,
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 9,
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 15,
    ],  
]
```

Knowing all those ids are unique, I want to simplify the array to something like:

```
$peeledResult = [
    0 => 22,
    1=> 9,
    2 => 15,
]
```

The following is my basic solution for it but I was wondering if there is a more elegant method to achieve the same.

```
$peeledResult = [];
foreach ($originalArray as $item) {
    $peeledResult[] = $role['id'];
}
```

Thanks for any advice in advance :)

Comment: Great, thanks @Rizier123. Just to confirm the `array_column()` method mentioned in [one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720619/4960774) does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (*Return the values from a single column in the input array*)

```
$new = array_column($originalArray, 'id');
```

Or [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) -

```
$new = array_map(function($x) {
  return $x['id'];
}, $originalArray);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(22)
  [1]=>
  int(9)
  [2]=>
  int(15)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @b0s3, sorry i was a bit late to accept your answer before the question flagged as duplicated.

Comment: But to be fair the `array_column()` method offered in the other question does the job much cleaner, so thanks to @Rizier123 too ;)