# Transpose csv file data

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I need help to assign `keys` to an `array` in PHP.

**My code is:**

```
//First I make an array of a csv file
$file="C:\path-to-csv\file.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
```

The `array`:

```
//echo json_encode($array);
["0","20150717","2:57:00","1437145020","1.56084","1.56096","1.56084","1.56094","5"],
["1","20150717","2:56:00","1437144960","1.56071","1.56089","1.56071","1.56089","9"],
["2","20150717","2:55:00","1437144900","1.5607","1.5607","1.56064","1.56064","2"], //continue
```

From the result of `$array`, I need to assign a specific `key` to a specific column and create a new `array` "`$newArray`". So, the result looks like this:

```
//$newArray should print:
"ID" :  [0, 1, 2],                      //I would like delete this value
"n"  :  [20150717, 20150717, 20150717], //I would like delete this value
"d"  :  [2:57:00, 2:56:00, 2:55:00],    //I would like delete this value
"t"  :  [1437145020, 1437144960, 1437144900], //column 4
"o"  :  [1.56084, 1.56071, 1.5607],     //column 5
"h"  :  [1.56096, 1.56089, 1.5607],     // column 6
"l"  :  [1.56084, 1.56071, 1.56064],    // column 7
"c"  :  [1.56094, 1.56089, 1.56064],    //column 8
"v"  :  [5, 9, 2]                      //column 9
```

I have tried to  do it through loops and some functions such as `array_fill_keys` and `array_column` but I can not get the desired result. I would greatly appreciate if you can help me, the `$array` has more than 1000 entries so it would be really important to optimize the code execution speed, and honestly exceeds my knowledge and I have not seen anything in Google to help me accomplish this.
Thanks for your time, sorry for my grammar.

Comment: One way to optimise would be to use a loop and `fgetcsv()` instead of `$csv= file_get_contents($file);`.... because you're still demanding a large chunk of memory for 1000 entries-worth of `$csv`

Comment: See this question, it might help I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Comment: @buff Yes, I saw a few hours ago but I could not transfer it to my code, I'll keep reading ... Thanks anyway :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5, you can make use of `array_column`:

```
$newArray = array(
    't' => array_column($array, 3),
    'o' => array_column($array, 4),
    'h' => array_column($array, 5),
    ...
);
```

If you're using an older PHP, you can find a PHP implementation of it at [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: I choose this answer as best because it took   `0.06900` and the answer of @JungleZombie took  `0.12100 ` both work great so thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Pretty much, this solution can be used <5.5, when array_column is not available to you.

More than 1000 entries does not seem to be that much for a foreach loop.

```
$keys = array('t','o','h','l','c','v');    
$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $j) {
    $r = array_slice($j, 3);
    foreach ($r as $i => $v) $newArray[$keys[$i]][] = $v*1; 
}
```

Json encoded result will be

```
"t":[1437144900,1437144900,1437145020],
"o":[1.5607,1.5607,1.56084],
"h":[1.5607,1.5607,1.56096],
"l":[1.56064,1.56064,1.56084],
"c":[1.56064,1.56064,1.56094],
"v":[2,2,5]
```

Running an array containing 10.000 entries took

```
0.020426
```

You can test yourself on [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s1yi-hq60).