# How to convert a multidimensional array into single dimensional array without using foreach method

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to convert a multidimensional array into single dimensional array without using foreach method

```
Array
    (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [opportunityid] => 5
               [id] => 89
               [discountedpackagecost] => 89990.00
               [discountedaddoncost] => 61000.00
               [title] => This is a very big title okayyyyyyy???????
           )

       [1] => Array
           (
               [opportunityid] => 42
               [id] => 90
               [discountedpackagecost] => 45592.00
               [discountedaddoncost] => 0.00
               [title] => test book
           )

    )
```

I just need only the Key->"id" form each rows.

Any default methods available in php??

I just expect the result to be like this.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "89" [1]=> string(2) "90" }
```

Comment: You can take a look at phps array functions, namely the `array_walk_...()` family. But those use loops themselves too, so what is the point here?

Comment: I know that some default functions are having inbuilt loop. I just want those functions to have inbuilt loops without making us to create a  custom loop.

Comment: OK, that sounds like the array functions php offers are just what you are looking for. The php documentation contains a full list with good examples of the functions usages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_column` in PHP 5.5 or newer

```
$array = array(
               array(
                  'id' => 1,
                  'name' => 'foo'
               ),
               array(
                  'id' => 2,
                  'name' => 'bar'
               )
         );

$ids= array_column($array, 'id');
print_r($ids);
```

[Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: array_column function not supporting less than 5.5 versions in PHP

Comment: @SaiDeepak I know and I have mentioned it in my answer. 5.5 or newer!!

Comment: Yeah i knew it but i am just asking is there any method

Comment: @SaiDeepak No of the self method until PHP 5.4 but there are many ways to accomplish it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php