# Combining multidimensional array to single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array structure

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1',
    'post_title' => 'Hello world!',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '79',
    'post_title' => 'ffffffffffff',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1720',
    'post_title' => 'Git primer',
  ),
)
```

I will love to convert it to a structure similar to the one below. Is there any php function that can do this? I am trying to avoid repetitive foreach loop.

```
array (
'1' => 'Hello world!',
'79' => 'ffffffffffff',
'1720' => 'Git primer',
)
```

Comment: a simple foreach + `$new_array[$v['ID']] = $v['post_title'];` why in the world wouldn't you want a foreach, it'll just take less than 4 lines

Comment: I will repeat my comment from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750886/php-mapping-a-multi-dimensional-into-an-associative-array#comment64875556_38750886

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `array_column()`to get this.

`Array_column()` function return all column name you have specify in parameter.

```
$array=array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1',
    'post_title' => 'Hello world!',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '79',
    'post_title' => 'ffffffffffff',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1720',
    'post_title' => 'Git primer',
  ),
)
$new_array = array_column($array, 'post_title', 'ID');
print_r($new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Hello world!
    [79] => ffffffffffff
    [1720] => Git primer
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

//Your array

```
$test = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1',
    'post_title' => 'Hello world!',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '79',
    'post_title' => 'ffffffffffff',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1720',
    'post_title' => 'Git primer',
  ),
);
```

//Solution:

```
foreach ($test as $t){
    $new_array[$t['ID']] = $t['post_title'];

}
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($new_array);
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using following

```
array_column($array,'post_title','ID');
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Hello world!
    [79] => ffffffffffff
    [1720] => Git primer
)
```