# Extracting keys (stored in child array) from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array as:

```
$array = [
    ['key' => 'foo', 'value' => 'fooVal'],
    ['key' => 'bar', 'value' => 'barVal'],
];
```

Is there an easy way of extracting the keys so that I have `['foo', 'bar']` or I must loop through `$array`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to get values of a single column from an array

```
$array = [
    ['key' => 'foo', 'value' => 'fooVal'],
    ['key' => 'bar', 'value' => 'barVal'],
];

$result = array_column( $array , 'key' ); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

Doc: [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)