# Convert output array

Tags: php, codeigniter

here i have an array that i want to convert the output of.

here is the function:

```
public function access($key)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT box_role.group_id FROM box_role INNER JOIN box_menu ON box_role.menu_id=box_menu.id WHERE box_menu.key='$key'")->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

and these are the results:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [group_id] => 1
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [group_id] => 2 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [group_id] => 4 
    ) 
);
```

but I would like the output to be like this:

```
$new_array = array(1, 2, 4);
```

Comment: `$query = array_column($query, 'group_id');` (ps: you really should read the docs - you are totally open to sql injections with this method ...)

Comment: thats work..... 
thanks :)

Comment: @NigelRen i won't do that for an one liner - i'm not the type of guy who wants to collect points by all means ;)

Comment: @sintakonte, found a way of not having to answer it- I've found something to flag it as a duplicate instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your are looking for is a function called `array_column`

In your specific case it should be

```
public function access($key)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT box_role.group_id FROM box_role INNER JOIN box_menu ON box_role.menu_id=box_menu.id WHERE box_menu.key='$key'")->result_array();
    $query = array_column($query, 'group_id');

    return $query;
}
```

> you can find more information about that topic on the official docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**the output is like this

```
[
  0 => 
    [group_id] => 1,
  1 => 
    [group_id] => 2,
  2 => 
    [group_id] => 4 ,
]
```

its an array of arrays

if you want the array values only, you can use

`array_values($arr)`