# Get each 2nd value of an array containing several entries in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Good evening,

I have an array of 4 entries and each entry has 3 informations

```
1st entry:
field1 -> John
field2 -> 21
field3 -> 2020-06-05T19:58:53Z

2nd entry:
field1 -> Romeo
field2 -> 22
field3 -> 2020-06-05T19:48:00Z

3rd entry:
field1 -> Juliet
field2 -> 20
field3 -> 2020-06-05T18:38:10Z

4th entry:
field1 -> Mike
field2 -> 98
field3 -> 2020-06-05T19:22:22Z
```

Now, what I would like to achieve is to retrieve (browse) the respective value of the second field (namely 21, 22, 20, 98). Is there a smart way to achieve this or do I need to query each record?

I was planning to use :

```
foreach ($mystack as $value)
{
}
```

.. but maybe, I'm taking the wrong approach?

Please bear with me as I am a complete newbie with php :)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That's the way to do it. `echo $value['field2'];`

Comment: It's in my comment, you access it by the index/field name.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `array_column()` function to extract all those values into an array.

```
foreach (array_column($mystack, 'field2') as $field2) {
    echo $field2 . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar for your support and help. Have a nice evening

Comment: @Laurent - please set this answer as accepted if you're satisfied :-)