# Get data from json array PHP range [0] => Array , [1] => Array

Tags: php, json, get

I need help. Please, I have a service that I have no control over that shows me formatted data Json

> echo print_r( $data);

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [user] => one
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user] => two
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user] => three
    )
```

)

I want to get the data

```
one
two
three
```

How can I do that?

Thank You ,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use foreach,

```
foreach($yourdata as $data)
{
 echo $data['user'];
}
```

this will give you all user .